# excess border/padding appearing at the bottom of my html

Tags: jquery, css, html

so I was trying the [jquery superslide plugin](http://nicinabox.com/superslides/) on [my web](http://anesthetize.es/zine/simple2.html) and I get an unexpected "padding in the bottom of my page. I suspects this is because the display area is not calculated properly or a margin is messing the html, but I can't figure it out. Thank you!

**Update:** it turns out that a &nbsp is appearing at the end of the html document (as can be figured out validating the site). I tried editing it and getting rid of spaces/newlines after the  tag to no avail. What am I doing wrong :(

Comment: Moar code. We need you to give us something or we cannot help you...

Comment: @shesmovedon - The problem is this `</html>&nbsp` in your source.

Comment: @eithedog I tried to validate my code and found out about this, but I literally don't know how to fix it as there is no space or newline in the source :/

Comment: @shesmovedon it might be added by your hoster, in case it's not in the html file. You can run `$(document.body).html($(document.body).children());` before running any jquery scripts to remove first and last textNode children of body (as such - this &nbsp;)

Comment: @eithedog this solved the issue. Do you have any clue as to why a hosting would do this? thanks a lot! (if you want, you can answer it properly so I can mark it as the solution)

Comment: @shesmovedon I'd say either misconfiguration or putting nbsp instead of a banner (free hostings generally put a random banner before or after `html`). Done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appeared to be a `&nbsp` appearing out of nowhere at the end of the file.

Targeting such node via CSS proved unsuccessful, so I've suggested the jquery approach of filtering text nodes via: `$(document.body).html($(document.body).children());` (bear in mind that this will remove all first and last text nodes - so this solution requires at least one non-text child of body to display "proper" content)

See question comments for more info.